# 'OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use' on deploying on kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy a Python application on Google Kubernetes Engine using Python's Flask API. After deploying application I am hitting the 'OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use'.

I assumed that the error could be because of the port number and I tried changing the port number on gunicorn config file but still encountered the same issue.

These are the files that I am using
gunicorn_config.py

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
accesslog = "-" # STDOUT
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
loglevel = "debug"
capture_output = True
enable_stdio_inheritance = True
```

The following is the Dockerfile I am using to deploy the application:

```
# python runtime
FROM ubuntu as intermediate

# install git
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

# add credentials on build
ARG ACCESS_TOKEN
RUN git config --global url."https://${ACCESS_TOKEN}:@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

ARG BRANCH
RUN git clone https://github.com/org_name/rest_api.git -b "${BRANCH}"


FROM python:3.6-stretch




# copy the repository form the previous image
COPY --from=intermediate rest_api rest_api


# working directory
WORKDIR /rest_api/id_generation


# install requirements
RUN pip3 install -r ./src/requirements.txt

# make port 8000 available to the world outside
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "./conf/gunicorn_config.py", "src.main:app"]
```

This the Kubernetes command I am using to deploy on Kuberenetes Engine

```
kubectl run deployment_name --image-pull-policy=Always --overrides='
{
    "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta1",
    "kind": "Deployment",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "deployment_name",
        "labels": {
            "app": "deployment_name"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "matchLabels": {
                "app": "deployment_name"
            }
        },
        "template": {
            "metadata": {
                "labels": {
                    "app": "deployment_name"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": "deployment_name",
                        "image": "gcr.io/project_name/id_generator:development",
                        "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                        "ports": [
                            {
                                "containerPort": 8000
                            }
                        ],
                        "volumeMounts": [
                            {
                                "name": "credentials",
                                "readOnly": true,
                                "mountPath":"/rest_api/keys"
                            }
                        ],
                        "env":[
                            {
                                "name":"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",
                                "value":"/rest_api/keys/key.json"
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"ENVIRONMENT",
                                "value":"development"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "name": "credentials",
                        "secret": {
                            "secretName": "credentials"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'  --image=gcr.io/project_name/deployment_name:development --port 8000
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Just based on what you've shown, that error shouldn't occur: GUnicorn will be the only process running in its container and the container should have an isolated network namespace.  How are you actually launching it?  What code actually produces the error?  Is there a backtrace?  Do you only see the error on GKE, or does it also reproduce on simpler environments like local Docker or a Python virtual environment?

Comment: The error is seen on Kubernetes' pods logs after deployment on GKE. I have updated my question with the Kubectl run command that I use to deploy this application.

Comment: That's an interesting way to launch the pod.  Can you take the JSON blob from the `--overrides` option, write it into a separate file, and run `kubectl apply -f deployment.json` instead of that command?  (If you `kubectl describe deployment deployment_name`, does it show _two_ containers in the pod spec and not just one?)

Comment: How do I take the JSON blob from the --overrides option? Can you please let me know?

Comment: this is unrelated to the container. This is likely due to an issue with 2 nodes sharing the same pod CIDR so when the pod is coming up, it tries to grab an IP address being used by another node. cordon the node where the pod is currently, then delete the pod so it schedules to a different node. If it works on the new node, delete the currently cordoned node

Comment: Why not use a yaml file with `kubectl apply` to deploy? It is curious because you're not trying to get a node port, and the container should run smoothly. If you test locally using docker or minikube, it works?